# Rails has_many index column can't be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I am making a Message model, the association is

```
User has_many messages
Message belongs_to user
```

There are two kind of messages, one is public and the other is private. It depends on its `is_public` column.

Here is my **message schema**

```
create_table "messages", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content",    limit: 65535
  t.boolean  "is_public"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree
end
```

I think only private message should contain `user_id`.

However, I found out that I can't create `message` directly.

For example

```
m = Message.create
=> #<Message:0x007fa6724e9d80 id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, is_public: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Message.count 
=> 0
User.first.messages << m
Message.count
=> 1
```

Is there a better way I can keep the `index` and create `message` without associating?

Comment: did you check the error that is prohibiting you from creating a new record? like `a=Message.create; a.errors`

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but since a message belongs to a user, you cannot create a message without an associated user_id.

If your question is how to create a message without the extra line `User.first.messages << m`, then I think you can solve that by doing `Message.create(user: User.first)`

Comment: @illusionist, thanks. I didn't know there's way to show error message.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKale, sorry I am not trying to remove the extra line, I am searching a way which can create a message without an associated `user_id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of rails are you using

But if you're using Rails 5, whenever you define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default

You can set "required" to false to skip that

```
class  Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, required: false
end
```

[Please read this for further details](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html)

Comment: Yes, I am using Rails 5. Thanks, it works perfectly, and the reference is great, too.